# XAMPP not running on Windows 7

Tags: xampp

I have installed XAMPP on Windows 7 ulimate successfully. But the following error was found during running Apache from XAMPP Control Panel:

Problem detected!
Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" - defaults-file....
MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure my SQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Please help solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you not understanding the error? MySQL Server is running, which is taking the port that XAMPP's own mysql server wants to use. If MySQL Server is on automatic start, you'll have to turn that off, kill the process/service, and then XAMPP will work.

Answer (score 0):

The message clearly says the port 3306 is being used by MySQL server. So XAMPP fails to bind to the same port.To launch XAMPP successfully, kill the MySQL server process. Then try restarting XAMPP.